# WordPress Category custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Hi I want to filter posts with custom category fields. I created custom field and it's working.

```
/*  Custom Field for Categories.
    ======================================== */

// Add new term page
function my_taxonomy_add_meta_fields( $taxonomy ) { ?>
    <div class="form-field term-group">
        <label for="show_category">
          <?php _e( 'Show Category', 'codilight-lite' ); ?> <input type="checkbox" id="show_category" name="show_category" value="yes" />
        </label>
    </div><?php
}
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'my_taxonomy_add_meta_fields', 10, 2 );

// Edit term page
function my_taxonomy_edit_meta_fields( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    $show_category = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'show_category', true ); ?>

    <tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="show_category"><?php _e( 'Show Category', 'codilight-lite' ); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show_category" name="show_category" value="yes" <?php echo ( $show_category ) ? checked( $show_category, 'yes' ) : ''; ?>/>
        </td>
    </tr><?php
}
add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'my_taxonomy_edit_meta_fields', 10, 2 );

// Save custom meta
function my_taxonomy_save_taxonomy_meta( $term_id, $tag_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'show_category' ] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'show_category', 'yes' );
    } else {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'show_category', '' );
    }
}
add_action( 'created_category', 'my_taxonomy_save_taxonomy_meta', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'edited_category', 'my_taxonomy_save_taxonomy_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Now I want to filter posts which show category select box checked yes. I'm trying query like this but it's not working

```
$argswp = array( 
'post_type' => "post",
'tax_query' => array( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'season',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'yes'
    )),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($argswp);
```

I tried slug or id in field section by the way it's still not working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
$seasons = get_categories(
    array(
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => '0',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'show_category',
                'value'   => 'yes',
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to adjust the options more. Specifically the terms, taxonomy, and field

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. What can I adjust?

Comment: The values for the array pulling the posts